# SQL Server Backup/Restore with Progress indicator

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a backup and restore program for windows form application which is working fine for me. I need to put this code inside a thread or background worker to show the progress of operation in percentage completed. Below is my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
if (rdBackup.Checked)
{
    SaveFileDialog svdlg = new SaveFileDialog();
    svdlg.Filter = "Sql Server Database Backup File *.bak|*.bak";

    svdlg.ShowDialog();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(svdlg.FileName))
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Variables.ConStr);
        cn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        cmd.CommandText = @"BACKUP DATABASE [" + cn.Database.ToString() + "] TO DISK = '" + svdlg.FileName + "'";

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cn;

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Database backup successful.");
    }
}
else
{
    btnBackupRestore.Text = "&Restore Database";

    OpenFileDialog opdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    opdlg.Filter = "SQL Server Database Backup File *.bak|*.bak";

    opdlg.ShowDialog();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(opdlg.FileName))
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Variables.ConStr);
        cn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        cmd.CommandText = @"use master;ALTER DATABASE [" + cn.Database.ToString() + "] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate;  " +
                 "RESTORE DATABASE [" + cn.Database.ToString() + "] FROM DISK = '" + opdlg.FileName + "'"
                 + "ALTER DATABASE [" + cn.Database.ToString() + "] SET Multi_User ";

        //cmd.CommandText = "DBCC CHECKDB ('[" + cn.Database.ToString() + "]')";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = cn;

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        cn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Database restored successfully.");
    }
}
```

Comment: ***WHY*** are you using a `SqlDataReader` ? There's no data to be read - use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead !

Comment: Also, you should use the `DialogResult` that is being returned from the `ShowDialog` method to decide whether the dialog was successful - or not. `DialogResult result = ShowDialog(); if (result == DialogResult.OK) { ...... }`

Comment: Thx for correction @marc_s

Comment: On the `SqlConnection`, there is an event `InfoMessage` that you can hook into to get the notificiations that you'd normally see in SQL Server Management Studio. See [detailed documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: In addition to the `InfoMessage` event handler @marc_s mentioned, add `WITH STATS=1` to the `RESTORE` statement to get progress about every 1 percent (or whatever you need).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the 10,20,30,40... messages sents during backup to the SSMS window and prepare some kind of progress bar to show these advancements then you need use the [SMO libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-2017) (Sql Server Management Objects)

The code to receive these message and execute a backup is the following

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(".......")) 
{
    ServerConnection svrConnection = new ServerConnection(con);
    Server server = new Server(svrConnection);
    Backup bk = new Backup();
    bk.PercentComplete += pctComplete;
    bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    bk.Database = con.Database
    bk.Devices.Add(new BackupDeviceItem(svdlg.FileName, DeviceType.File));
    bk.SqlBackup(server);
```

}

```
void pctComplete(object server, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Percent);
}
```

The Restore operation is similar

Comment: i tried smo libraries but these are hard to deploy on client side and have no luck with these as well.

Comment: Usually with the NuGet packag manager is not very difficult to have everythng you need to distribute in your app